# If a field contains null then entire concatenate result is null

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to concatenate for a label. If a field contains `null` then entire concatenate result is `null`.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PMAByPC(string PartnerCode)
{
    var result = (from N in _POSContext.PMAs
                  where (N.PartnerCode == PartnerCode)
                  select new 
                  { 
                      label = N.Address1 + " | " + N.Address2 + " | " + N.City, 
                      id = N.ID 
                  });

    return Json(result);
}
```

Here, if data is not present in of the fields, label becomes `null`.

I tried with

`select new { label = N.Address1 ?? "?" + " | " + N.Address2 ?? "?" + " | " + N.City ?? "?", id = N.ID }`

then it takes only `N.Address1` value and ignores the rest of the fields.

Comment: Does string interpolation i.e. `new { label = $"{N.Address1}|{N.Address2}|{N.City}", id = N.ID }` give the same results? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Its working...string interpolation is as expected in this case.

Comment: String interpolation works because the expression is evaluated client side (C#).

Comment: General advice: 1) never return live queries to the MVC pipeline. 2) use the asynchronous features of Entity Framework Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a standard SQL string concatenation behavior (the same happens with SqlServer database).

If you want to evaluate the concatenation server side (database), you need to convert `null` to empty string `""` (or something else) using the `??` operator. Similar to your attempt, but you've missed the C# operator precedence. The way you wrote it is equivalent of

```
N.Address1 ??
(
  ("?" + " | " + N.Address2) ??
  (
      ("?" + " | " + N.City) ?? "?"
  )
)
```

which is not what was the intent.

You can avoid such issues by enclosing similar conversions with brackets:

```
select new
{
    label = (N.Address1 ?? "?") + " | " + (N.Address2 ?? "?") + " | " + (N.City ?? "?"),
    id = N.ID,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard compliant and reasonable behavior: if you concatenate a string with an unknown string, the result is unknown.

Use the `coalesce` function for that:

```
coalesce(col1, '') || coalesce(col2, '')
```